MEM_LOAD_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM and MEM_LOAD_UOPS_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM are the same?
I found in perfmon-events.intel.com that Haswell do not support MEM_LOAD_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM. It only support MEM_LOAD_UOPS_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM.
Here is the detail:
MEM_LOAD_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM means Retired load instructions which data sources missed L3 but serviced from local DRAM.
MEM_LOAD_UOPS_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM means This event counts retired load uops where the data came from local DRAM. This does not include hardware prefetches.
So, my question is that dose Haswell have the same event?
I mean, I think they are not the same. MEM_LOAD_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM includes more instructions (not just micro-operations).
